# How to get array of function pointers to stop putting functions into RAM on ARM Cortex M0 and GCC

Tags: gcc, linker, arm, function-pointers

I'm using ARM GCC 10.2.1 20201103 and am running out of memory because I have an array of functions (short example below) and GCC is putting the array (or perhaps the functions) into RAM instead of .text.

The code looks like this:

```
static int16_t* (*func_arr[])(int16_t) = {
    func1,
    func2,
    func3,
    func4,
};
```

I've tried playing with **attribute**((section ("text"))), "static", "const", but I'm getting this message regardless:

```
motor6.elf section `._user_heap_stack' will not fit in region `RAM'
```

For every function I add to the array, I run out of memory by an additional 32 bytes or so, which makes me think the functions themselves are being put into RAM, though I'm unsure.

Anyone have ideas?

Comment: so make it `const`.. `the functions themselves` No, the function _pointers_ are put into RAM.

Comment: static affects the scope or visibility of that variable/array (label).  it can only be used either within that file or in that function depending on where in the file it lives, it does not make it a constant and does not move it into .text nor .rodata.   Const with or without the static is what you want if you want to move it from .data into .text or .rodata.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Each function I was including on the list was using static data.  So for each function that I added to the list, that amount of static data was added to the  RAM section.  Resolving this just means that the functions referenced in the list need to declare their data const static instead of just static.

Answer (score 0):

Make variables `const` to let compiler put it in read-only memory.

```
static int16_t *(*const func_arr[])(int16_t) = {
    func1,
    func2,
    func3,
    func4,
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I've tried that -- same story -- every time I add a function to the list I run out of RAM by an additional 32 bytes.